# how to show a image folder?

Tags: android, image, directory, horizontalscrollview

y have this code to show 3 images in a HorizontalScrollView it works perfect, but i need to show the images from a folder, and I dont know the specific number of files, so how can i show a unspecific number of images from a folder X??

Someone help please :)

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/mc1" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/mc2" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/bk1" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/bk2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: what you're looking for is a list view, or a gird view, do some google searching and you can find many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Give your layout an id (myLinearLayout in this ex below), loop through the folder and create a new imageview and add it to your layout

```
File sdDir = new File("FOLDER PATH");
File[] sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles();
for(File singleImageFile : sdDirFiles){
    ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(context);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(singleImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    myLinearLayout.addView(myImageView);
}
```

Make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have 2 problems with that, *context, cannot be resolved to a variable, and, getabsolutepath(), same error.


And, another doubt, can I use a folder in my program, i mean, not a SD folder, just another folder but no the defaults... sorry for my bad english im from Chile. Thx for your time my friend.

Comment: @user2962179 this wasn't meant to be copy/paste code. Just to show you how it would be done. You can get all the files from your Assets folder instead if you want. But if you don't know how to get a context, then i suggest you look up more tutorials.